# Whats the status of my HDD ? it freezes time to time

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, hard-disk, smartctl

Just a random day my win 7 froze and crashed with blue screen , i thought it was power problem as the battery was almost dead so i changed it and installed Linux dual boot ,was fine for few weeks but it happened again ,with both win and linux ,on linux i noticed corrupted sectors in busybox and really frequent so it just hit me whether HDD was about to die ,i did Smartctl test and it showed 'OK' but it got worse with HDD not showing up during boot and failing to even detect sometimes ,I did a clean LinuxMint install and it didnt change a thing but got worse in Boot ...
So any way

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-74-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABF...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050
Serial Number:    Y4NOTF2ST
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 5e1b88b6e
Firmware Version: AM0P1D
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Mar 23 19:17:04 2022 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 116) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 128
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1083
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   076   076   000    Old_age   Always       -       9908
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4249
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       189
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       133
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       112315
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 21/55)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       136059899
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       497385650
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       9579
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39725304303
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       54450583368
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 810 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 810 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9908 hours (412 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 50 f0 10 09 00 40   240 sectors at LBA = 0x00000910 = 2320

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 09 00 40 00      00:02:24.559  READ DMA EXT
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:02:24.553  [RESERVED]
  25 00 01 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:24.484  READ DMA EXT
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:02:24.478  [RESERVED]
  25 00 40 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:24.338  READ DMA EXT

Error 809 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9908 hours (412 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 50 20 20 08 00 40   32 sectors at LBA = 0x00000820 = 2080

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 40 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:24.338  READ DMA EXT
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:02:24.264  [RESERVED]
  25 00 00 00 09 00 40 00      00:02:24.186  READ DMA EXT
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:02:24.175  [RESERVED]
  25 00 01 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:24.101  READ DMA EXT

Error 808 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9908 hours (412 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 50 20 20 08 00 40   32 sectors at LBA = 0x00000820 = 2080

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 40 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:24.023  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:23.944  READ DMA EXT
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:02:23.934  [RESERVED]
  25 00 40 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:23.856  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 c0 40 06 10 40 00      00:02:23.856  READ DMA EXT

Error 807 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9908 hours (412 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 50 10 30 08 00 40   16 sectors at LBA = 0x00000830 = 2096

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 40 00 08 00 40 00      00:02:23.856  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 c0 40 06 10 40 00      00:02:23.856  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 40 00 06 10 40 00      00:02:23.855  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 07 10 40 00      00:02:23.852  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 c0 40 04 10 40 00      00:02:23.852  READ DMA EXT

Error 806 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9908 hours (412 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 50 b0 50 09 00 40   176 sectors at LBA = 0x00000950 = 2384

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 09 00 40 00      00:02:23.660  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 40 00 00 00 40 00      00:02:23.633  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 3c 38 10 00 40 00      00:02:22.542  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:02:22.541  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  b1 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:02:22.540  DEVICE CONFIGURATION FREEZE LOCK [OBS-ACS-3]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9906         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               40%      9906         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9764         -
# 4  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      60%      9763         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8985         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2007         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1377         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1377         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1334         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1246         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         4         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         1         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Thats the result of smartctl ,should i change my HDD?

Answer (score 1):

The drive seems fine (though I still recommend running `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/device` - that may take hours) but `UDMA_CRC_Error_Count` is insanely high. Please try replacing your SATA cable and cleaning the contact pads with pure alcohol.